# Django app in Azure - OperationalError at /edit_profile/ (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\x9B' for column 'first_name' at row 1")

Tags: mysql, django, azure, encoding, collation

I have Django app hosted on Azure that is connected to MySQL database (Azure Database for MySQL). I wanted to edit my profile so I put ść (for testing purposes) in First name and I got the following error:

```
OperationalError at /edit_profile/
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\x9B\\xC4\\x87' for column 'first_name' at row 1")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_profile/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\x9B\\xC4\\x87' for column 'first_name' at row 1")

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 84, in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py, line 73, in execute
            return self.cursor.execute(query, args) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py, line 206, in execute
        res = self._query(query) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py, line 319, in _query
        db.query(q) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py, line 259, in query
        _mysql.connection.query(self, query) …
▶ Local vars
The above exception ((1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC5\\x9B\\xC4\\x87' for column 'first_name' at row 1")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
```

My server parameners on Azure are:

character_set_server = utf8mb4 (utf8 is not working too)

collation_server = utf8_general_ci

From what I know Django uses utf-8 by default so my question is what can I do to let users use Polish, French, German etc. letters in their usernames, first names and last names?

EDIT:

The solution to this problem was much simpler than I thought. I checked enconding in all tables and apparently the default encoding was set up to `latin1_swedish_ci` instead of `uft8mb4`. I specified it in my database options:

```
    'OPTIONS': {
    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
    'init_command': 'SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;'
                    'SET collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;'
                    "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';"
                    "SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;"},
```

and changed enconding in all existiong tables.

Comment: If you are copying traceback from the browser use ```Switch to copy-and-paste view```, otherwise copy it directly from the terminal.

Comment: It seems a double escaping.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - Would you care to elaborate?  I don't think it is either "double escaping" or "double encoding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hex C59B C487 is the UTF-8 encoding for `ść`.

What are the connection settings?  They should be something like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    },
}
my.cnf:

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
default-collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

utf8mb4 (MySQL's term) is the same as UTF-8 (the outside world's term).  It includes the encoding for 'all' languages in the world.  That includes Polish, French, German, Chinese, Cherokee, Klingon, etc.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` should also say that utf8mb4 is being used for the columns that need to contain `ść`, etc.

Many charset issues are discussed [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored), but I don't think this problem is included.  Still, if you run into other problem, check out that Q&A.

If you are using a "terminal", be sure that it, *too*, is working with UTF-8.  For Windows' "cmd", see `chcp 65001`.